# Can a paladin cast Speak with animals?

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin, rituals

I have a paladin in my campaign that through "Oath of the Ancients" has the Speak with Animals spell, but that's a ritual spell and Paladins don't have ritual spell casting as a class feature. Can he still cast the spell or does he have to get something first?

Answer (score 26):

The ritual tag identifies spells that *can* be cast as rituals, not spells that *must* be cast as rituals.  Your Paladin can cast *Speak With Animals* as a regular Paladin spell using the normal rules.

From the [SRD](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/spellcasting/whatIsASpell.htm):

> Certain spells have a special tag: ritual. Such a spell can be cast following the normal rules for spellcasting, or the spell can be cast as a ritual.